# Can "fainted" and "lost consciousness" be interchanged?

Tags: meaning

Fainted (dictionary.com):

> A temporary loss of consciousness resulting from a decreased flow of blood to the brain

It says that "fainted" is a loss of consciousness **from a decreased flow of blood**.

So, if I were to say:

> After hitting his head with a metal bat, he fainted away.

Would that not make sense because he didn't really "faint" away, but more like "lost consciousness" because of a concussion?

Comment: Is this in a medical report, or in a narrative at the corner bar?

Comment: They mean roughly the same thing, though "fainted" generally implies that the loss of consciousness was sudden and, eg, resulted in the individual falling down or otherwise exhibiting this loss in a marked physical fashion.  "Loss of consciousness" does not imply either way with regard to suddenness or physical signs.  (But "fainted" would not apply to someone who was "cold conked" with a baseball bat, eg.)

Comment: I've never heard of anyone "fainting" from a left hook to the face.

Comment: @HotLicks- "Cold CONKED"?  Are you trying to be polite - or do they not say "cold-cocked," in your neck of the woods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Lost consciousness* is a relatively technical phrase, and isn't that frequently used in informal conversation. It is an umbrella term that covers fainting among other reasons for losing consciousness.

*Fainting* is when someone loses consciousness with no obvious physical cause. It can be a medical issue (as [Centaurus mentioned](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/256851/14499)), because they stood up too fast, because they saw something disturbing, etc.

When someone loses consciousness due to physical trauma, in conversation one would usually say they got *knocked out*.

> He got hit in the head with a metal bat and it knocked him out.
>   He got knocked out by a metal bat to the head.

Answer (score 3):

One can lose consciousness for several reasons, not only because a traumatic skull injury but also because of any cerebrovascular disease, heart arrhythmias, licit or illicit drug overdose (alcohol included), very low blood pressure, etc.  It's a technical term and it may be a serious condition or not.  Fainting, on the other hand, is the everyday term and refers to the moment one loses consciousness.  If someone faints and doesn't recover consciousness in minutes, a medical diagnosis will have to be made.  You can't visit that person in hospital and simply hear 
"she fainted" when you ask what happened.  The doctor will have to tell you that "the reason she fainted is because she has had a stroke" (or whatever) and (if she hasn't recovered consciousness) "now she is in a coma".  I hope you can feel the difference.  **Fainting is the acute sudden condition.** and of course it implies losing consciousness.  Loss of consciousness, on the other hand, can be sudden or acute, but can also come gradually. As you can see, they are not always interchangeable.

PS. Forget the "decreased blood flow to the brain" as the sole physiopathological mechanism of fainting.